# Synchronize built in present UIViewController animation with other animations

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to sync the built in `UIViewController` animation with other animations?

I present my `UIViewController` using `present(_:animated:completion:)`

On the new `UIViewController` I change the status bar background color like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

(I have have extended the `UIApplication` class so I have a property `statusBarView` which returns `UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView`)

I also change the status bar to `.lightContent` from `.default`

Is there a way to sync the built in `UIViewController` present animation with the animations on the status bar (change to `.lightContent` and `backgroundColor`), or do I have to build custom transition animations?

Comment: setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() for status bar animation

Comment: @Savitha I use that. My question is how to build the animations so that they are all synced with the built in animation of `present(_:animated:completion:)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with simple UIAnimation,

```
UIView.animate(duration: 0.6, animate: {//You can do whatever you want with the presented view }, completion: {//present the desired view controller})
```